# Let $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x)\ge|x|^{\alpha}, \frac12\lt\alpha\lt1$ and $f(x)f(2x)\le|x|$ then find $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$

Tags: functions, inequality, functional-inequalities

> Let $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x)\ge|x|^{\alpha}, \frac12\lt\alpha\lt1$ and $f(x)f(2x)\le|x|$ for all $x$ in the deleted neighbourhood of zero then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=1/\alpha/0/$Does not exist?

$f(x)\ge|x|^\alpha\implies f(2x)\ge|2x|^\alpha$

Multiplying, $f(x)f(2x)\ge2^\alpha|x|^{2\alpha}$

Also, $f(x)f(2x)\le|x|$

Thus, $2^\alpha|x|^{2\alpha}\le|x|$

As an example, I am taking $\alpha=\frac34$

So, $2^\frac34|x|^3\le|x|$

Since $|x|$ is positive and non-zero, so, $2^\frac34|x|^2\le1\implies|x|^2\le2^{-\frac34}\implies|x|\le2^{-\frac38}\implies x\in[-2^{-\frac38}, 2^{-\frac38}]-\{0\}$

I had hoped to comment something about $f(x)$ with this example, but not able to do so.

Comment: The inequalities hold *in* a neighbourhood of zero, right? I mean, why are you deleting it in that case?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, the question mentions deleted neighbourhood of zero. I don't know the reason. Maybe after I figure out $f(x)$ then I can comment about it.

Comment: No worries, the answers below seem correct anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is necessarily positive in a deleted neighborhood of $0$. Also
$$
 |x| \ge f(x) f(2x) \ge f(x) |2x|^\alpha
$$
implies
$$
 0 \le f(x)  \le 2^{-\alpha} |x|^{1-\alpha}
$$
so that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$|x|\geq f(x)f(2x) \geq f(x)|2x|^{\alpha}$. Hence, $0 <f(x)\leq 2^{-\alpha} |x|^{1-\alpha}$. Conclusion: $f(x) \to 0$ as $ x \to 0$.